# Can we do dynamic SQL in From Clause in a Select Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can the select query inside a from clause be a dynamic sql?
For example

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql='SELECT * table'

SELECT t.*, a+b AS total_sum
FROM
(
   EXEC (@sql)
) t
```

If the above is not possible, how can we achieve this functionality? 
Of course the above query result in Error when run in sql server.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: use your dynamic sql to insert to a table and later you read it from there or why dont you make the whole thing dynamic?

Comment: @Hybridzz      Is it advisable to do it using temp table when the data in the  table is too large like a million or more records?

Comment: Check this answer to [Use SQL to filter the results of a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295383/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use dynamic table in from clause , you must run command `EXEC(@sql)` outside :
In your above example :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @dynamicSql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql='SELECT * table'

SET @dynamicSql ='SELECT t.*, a+b AS total_sum
FROM
(
   '+@sql+'
) t'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynamicSql
```

Comment: So basically put everything (outer select part as well) in one dynamic sql and Execute it. This definitely solves my problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, a SQL statement is compiled the first time the database sees it. This means that anything that can change the code being generated can't be a parameter. Which in turn means that you can't use parameters for...

- table names
- join expressions
- column names
- where clauses
- order by clause

In fact, you could say that you are more or less limited to using parameters for...

- Literal values in comparisons `MyColumn = @Param1`
- Literal values in select statements `SELECT @Param2`
- Literal values in insert/update statements `SET Column = @Param3`
- Top, limit, and fetch clauses `SELECT TOP @Param4`

As mentioned elsewhere, the work-around is to create your SQL as a string and then pass that string to `sp_executesql`.

---

Deep notes:

SQL is normally compiled into an intermediate language. This intermediate language can be viewed as XML. See "execution plans" for more information.

In SQL Server 2014, stored procedures can be converted into C++ code and then compiled to machine language. There are a lot of restrictions when doing this that are too much to discus here.